# Coupled functions $f,g$ satisfy $Lf(\lambda) = \frac{\beta}{\beta + \lambda} Lg(\lambda)$, solve for $f$

Tags: functional-analysis, laplace-transform, functional-equations

Let $\beta, \delta \geq 0$, $\beta + \delta > 0$. Let $f(t), g(t) : \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \rightarrow [0,1]$ satisfying the following equations:
$$f(t) = \int_{0}^t \beta e^{-\beta (t-s)} g(s) ds$$
$$g(t) = e^{-\delta t} + \int_{0}^{t} \delta e^{-\delta(t-s)}f(s) ds$$
From this I was able to derive the following identity:
$$Lf(\lambda) = \frac{\beta}{\beta + \lambda} Lg(\lambda),\text{ } \lambda > 0$$
where $L$ denotes the Laplace transform, that is $Lf(\lambda) = \int_{0}^\infty f(t)e^{-\lambda t}dt$. Now I would like to show that
$$f(t) = \frac{\beta}{\beta + \delta} \left(1-e^{-(\beta + \delta)t} \right)$$
I was unable to show this. I have tried playing around with the expressions, for example plugging in the definition of $g$ into the Laplace identity equation, but this lead nowhere. I am not very familiar with Laplace transforms, is there maybe some property I could use? Maybe apply an inverse Laplace transform? What can I try here?

Comment: Exp(0) = 1, so also f(0) = 0 in the last expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first compute $Lg(\lambda)$:
\begin{align}
Lg(\lambda)&=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-\lambda t}g(t)\,dt \\
&=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-\lambda t}\left(e^{-\delta t} + \int_{0}^{t} \delta e^{-\delta(t-s)}f(s)\,ds \right)dt \\
&=\frac{1}{\lambda+\delta}+\delta\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^te^{-(\lambda+\delta)t+\delta s}f(s)\,dsdt. \tag{1}
\end{align}
Interchanging the order of integration in the double integral yields
\begin{align}
Lg(\lambda)&=\frac{1}{\lambda+\delta}+\delta\int_0^{\infty}\int_s^{\infty}
e^{-(\lambda+\delta)t+\delta s}f(s)\,dtds \\
&=\frac{1}{\lambda+\delta}+\delta\int_0^{\infty}e^{\delta s}f(s)\frac{e^{-(\lambda+\delta)s}}{\lambda+\delta}\,ds \\
&=\frac{1}{\lambda+\delta}+\frac{\delta}{\lambda+\delta}\int_0^{\infty}
e^{-\lambda s}f(s)\,ds \\
&=\frac{1}{\lambda+\delta}\left[1+\delta\, Lf(\lambda)\right]. \tag{2}
\end{align}
Plugging $(2)$ into the identity
$$
Lf(\lambda) = \frac{\beta}{\beta + \lambda} Lg(\lambda) \tag{3}
$$
and solving for $Lf(\lambda)$ gives us
$$
Lf(\lambda)=\frac{\beta}{\lambda^2+(\beta+\delta)\lambda}=\frac{\beta}{\beta+\delta}\left(\frac{1}{\lambda}-\frac{1}{\lambda+\beta+\delta}\right). \tag{4}
$$
Applying the inverse Laplace transform to both sides of $(4)$ we finally obtain
$$
f(t) = \frac{\beta}{\beta + \delta} \left(1-e^{-(\beta + \delta)t} \right). \tag{5}
$$

Answer (score 1):

(Partial answer)

If I were you, I would use [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form:_differentiation_under_the_integral_sign) instead of Laplace transform. Indeed, one gets by differentiating $f$ and $g$ :
$$
\begin{cases}
   f'(t) = \beta g(t) - \beta f(t) \\
   g'(t) = \delta f(t) - \delta g(t)
\end{cases}
$$
This pair of differential equations may be recasted in a matrix form as
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} 
\begin{pmatrix} f \\ g \end{pmatrix} 
= 
\begin{pmatrix} -\beta & \beta \\ \delta & -\delta \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} f \\ g \end{pmatrix}
$$
and solved by $\Psi(t) = e^{At}\,\Psi_0$, where $\Psi(t) := (f(t),g(t))$ are the unknowns with the initial conditions $\Psi_0 = (f(0),g(0)) = (0,1)$ and $A$ is the matrix above. I let you compute its [exponential](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=MatrixExp%5B%7B%7B-b*t%2Cb*t%7D%2C%7Bd*t%2C-d*t%7D%7D%5D) and the final result.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that definitely works, however the exercise I'm doing states that one should use the identity with the Laplace to show it